# Getting Unexpected Error while obtaining screenshot - java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, screenshot

I am getting below error while capturing screenshot in Android Studio 2.0. I tried with 2 different tablets and with both of them I am getting this error.

```
Unexpected Error while obtaining screenshot - java.lang.Nullpointerexception
```

I have googled and also looked at different stackoverflow questions but didnt found any which can resolve this issue.

I have recently installed Android Studio 2.0 and this could be a problem I dont know.

Comment: I get that from time to time as well. It feels a bit like a possible memory issue, though I don't know for certain. Usually, it clears up for me if I restart Android Studio. Also, I am less prone to get this error if I close up the screenshot tab that Android Studio opens before I take the next screenshot.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. Let me try restarting the studio if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting the Android Studio worked for me.

It doesn't give the screen capture error after I restarted Android studio.

Answer (score 4):

*This is an old question but there is another specific reason why this can happen, and while it is clearly not OP's case, it might still help someone else:*

If you have `getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` set (normally used to avoid screenshots), it will also prevent you from taking screenshots from Android Studio, generating the same error `Unexpected Error while obtaining screenshot`.

Answer (score 2):

Goto AndroidStudio settings->System settings ->checked Support screen reader
and restart your android studio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvBa4.png)

Comment: In Android Studio 3.4-> Support screen reader moved to :
Settings-> Appearance->Accessibility