# Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, screenshot, jetbrains-ide

I am getting an error while taking screenshots from Android Studio 3.2.1, but working in another system (Android studio 3.1.3). Video capturing working perfectly.

It gives me below error.

> Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF

This is not a duplicate of [Nirali's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37145130/3778703),

I tried below options

**1:** Restarting the Android Studio worked for me.

It doesn't give the screen capture error after I restarted Android studio.

**2:** Go to Android Studio **Settings -> System settings -> checked Support screen reader** and restart your Android Studio.

[image]

**3:** `getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` is never used in my application.

What is a perfect solution for it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Still, I am getting this error, first times working then not working, In that case, I am enabling MTP in the device then again work for one time.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: @Phillen try to enabling MTP and take Screenshot may it work, some time it's working

Comment: Does anyone get resolved this error?  I am using Android Studio 3.3.2 and emulator android version 9.0 (28)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio errror tryin to get an screenshot : "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012909/android-studio-errror-tryin-to-get-an-screenshot-unexpected-error-while-obtai)

Comment: Same to me. All so unstable. Unusable, very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio 3.4:
Go to Settings-> Appearance->Accessibility-> Check screen reader

Answer (score 2):

I am facing this same problem after update android studio 3.5.2 and update the SDK from 26 to 28 then not getting a screenshot from Logcat.every time that displays below error which is connect with adb.exe:

"**Unexpected error while obtaining a screenshot from the device: EOF**"

**Then I have applied below solution and it's work for me:**

Step 1: Download adb.exe file again from [this Link.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)

Step 2: Replace this File from Your SDK file-path : *Android\sdk\platform-tools*

Step 3: Restart Your Android studio

Step 4: Take Screenshot from Logcat

Another one:

Go to Settings-> Appearance->Accessibility-> Check screen reader

Answer (score 1):

It might not work, For security application!. They would have protected from screenshots.

Comment: This is correct. If you use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE` on your window, this is the error that the Android emulator will report to you when you attempt to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Two of these options definitely worked for me. I had tried cycling adb as suggested in [this post last October](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012909) but it didn't change anything. I am still back on V3.2 Canary 14. This might have been fixed in later versions. But setting screen reader support in System settings gave me screenshots back.

Comment: Oops, #2 worked once then no matter what I did, I kept getting the EOF message.